# Can't resolve all parameters in validation directive during ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular8

I have go through with following questions but didn't found any solution.

- [Angular 4 directive error: Can't resolve all parameters for directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194125/angular-4-directive-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-directive)
- [Can't resolve all parameters for custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090874/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-custom-directive)

I have made a custom validation directive to validate unique permalink. this code working fine but when i try to create a build for production then it gives me following error:-

> ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for
>   UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective in
>   E:/Manish/Projects/ampleAdmin/src/app/shared/permalink-validation.directive.ts:
>   ([object Object], ?).

**permalink-validation.directive.ts**

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncValidator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as qs from 'qs';
import { PageService } from '../services/page.service';
import { IPage } from '../client-schema';

export function UniquePermalinkValidator(pageService: PageService, page: IPage): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (ctrl: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    if (!(ctrl && ctrl.value)) { return null; }

    const cond: any = {
      where: {
        permalink: ctrl.value
      }
    };

    if (page && page.id) {
      cond.where.id = { nin: [page.id]};
    }
    const query = qs.stringify(cond, { addQueryPrefix: true });

    return pageService.getPageCount(query).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res && res.count ? { uniquePermalink: true } : null;
      })
    );
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUniquePermalink]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor(private pageService: PageService, private page: IPage) { }

  validate(ctrl: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return UniquePermalinkValidator(this.pageService, this.page)(ctrl);
  }
}
```

**page.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { NotifierService } from 'angular-notifier';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { IPage } from 'src/app/client-schema';
import { Utils } from 'src/app/shared/utils';
import { PageService } from 'src/app/services/page.service';
import { UniquePermalinkValidator } from 'src/app/shared/permalink-validation.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  private notifier: NotifierService;

  pageForm: FormGroup;
  pageDetail: IPage;

  isAddFold = false;
  isEditFold = false;
  editFoldIndex = -1;

  constructor(
    private pageService: PageService,
    private notifierService: NotifierService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.notifier = notifierService;
  }

  initPageForm() {
    this.pageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(250)]],
      permalink: ['', [Validators.required], UniquePermalinkValidator(this.pageService, this.pageDetail)],
      folds: [
        []
      ],
      data: null,
      status: true
    });
  }
}
```

I am using single form for Add/Edit page so i have to require records details to allow permalink on editing a page.

is there any way to pass current page details to directive?

Comment: I'm going to guess based on the naming convention, which is not idiomatic by the way, that `IPage` Is just an interface. By definition, such a type annotation cannot be used to infer a dependency for injection.

Comment: Yes it is interface for page object. i have to require current page details on edit form to validate permalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
export function UniquePermalinkValidator(pageService: PageService, page: IPage): AsyncValidatorFn {
  // ...
}
```

And given

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUniquePermalink]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {    
  constructor(private pageService: PageService, private page: IPage) {}
  // ...
}
```

And given that `IPage` is defined *solely* by

```
export interface IPage {
  id: number;
  // ...
}
```

Then `UniquePermalinkValidatorDirective` will not work by definition, failing in the manner described.

An `interface` defines something only in *type* space, not in the *value* space and therefore has no runtime manifestation whatsoever. This means it cannot be used in a value position.

In essence, Angular's dependency injection system reads the *type* of constructor parameters and, when there is a correspondingly named declaration in the *value* space, it will use that correspondingly named value as the injection token.

For example, the following

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() export class Service {
    constructor(http: Http) {}
}
```

can also be written

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

export class Service {
    constructor(@Inject(Http) http: ThisTypeIsArbitraryWithRespectToInjection) {}
}
```

which means the same thing

Notice how `Http` is pass as an argument to `Inject`. But `Inject(IPage)`, where `IPage` is an `interface`, is malformed.

A primary purpose of `@Inject(ProviderToken)` is to allow one to inject a provider orthogonally to the type of the decorated paramater in cases such as yours.

Therefore, you need something like

```
constructor(@Inject(pageToken) page) {}
```

Which means one needs to define a token and use it to register a provider that can be injected.

One can, and should, still write

```
constructor(@Inject(pageToken) page: IPage) {}
```

In order to give the parameter a type but the type is unrelated to the value injected for the parameter.

For example

```
import {InjectionToken, NgModule} from '@angular/core';

export const pageToken = new InjectionToken<IPage>('Page');

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: pageToken,
      useFactory: functionReturningAPage
    }
  ]
 }) export class // ...
```